# How to quit an application running in gdb gracefully when the application isn't reponding.

Tags: debian, debugging, gdb

This is somewhat related to [gdb set overwrite logging on should overwrite gdb.txt correct?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396669/gdb-set-overwrite-logging-on-should-overwrite-gdb-txt-correct) .

Let's say I'm running a session of some application. For example purposes, let me take the example of qbittorrent again.

As shared before this is how a run happens -

```
$ gdb qbittorrent 
(gdb) set logging overwrite on 
(gdb) set logging on 
(gdb) set pagination 0
(gdb) run
```

one way I know is exiting the application gracefully but sometimes the application hangs/takes too much time or simply doesn't respond.

Then the only option which remains with me is using `CTRL+C` which if I understand correctly kills the underlying application, in our example qbittorrent and then am able to quit gdb by means of

```
(gdb) quit
```

Is/would there be any other way of quitting the application and still let the gdb session keep running or the only way is the crude way I mentioned above.

AFAI know killing an application process should be the last solution and not the first.

Comment: When running under `gdb` under default settings, Ctrl-C does not kill the application, just breaks into the debugger, where you can decide what to do. Use `cont` to "swallow" the signal, and the application continues undisturbed. Or use `signal 2` to pass the SIGINT (2) to the application. Or use `kill` to kill the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use signals for this. Before you start your program, set up `USR1` or `USR2` to break `gdb` without affecting the program:

```
handle SIGUSR1 nopass
```

Then you can run your program, and when you need to stop it, run `kill -USR1` from another shell with the appropriate (child) pid. `gdb` will pause the application, and you can then add breakpoints, examine state etc., and if you want to, continue the execution with `cont`.